# How to redirect to JSP and add values to the stack in EL

Tags: jsp

*I am getting confused with how to add values in stack in EL, how I should code*`How to redirect to JSP and add values to the stack in EL.`

Is this proper or not

```
@WebServlet (name="A", urlPatterns={"/next"}) 
@WebInitParam(name="test",value="annotation") 
@WebServlet (name="A", urlPatterns={"/next"},  initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="test",value="annotation")}
```

Comment: Use `<c:redirect>` JSTL

Comment: this is proper or not@WebServlet (name="A",
urlPatterns={"/next"})
@WebInitParam(name="test",value="annotation")


@WebServlet (name="A", urlPatterns={"/next"}, initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="test",value="annotation")}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting from a servet to jsp, then

```
ReqeustDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourJsp.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

For adding values, you can set request attributes directly.

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");
```

In the jsp in which you have forwarded,

```
#{requestScope.attributeName}
```

Comment: Yea but are you sure that these values will added in stack my point is that value should be added in stack.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
<c:redirect url="index-userapp.jsp">
  <c:param name="co"
        value="${param.co}"></c:param>
</c:redirect>
```

Comment: where `co` is an existing parameter in the request that originated the current jsp